# Not a valid parameter definition Swagger.json

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I have this swagger definition

```
/memberdetails/Prospect:
    post:
      tags:
        - memberdetails
      summary: Create member details using member object.
      operationId: memberdetails.Prospect
      parameters:
        - name: authenticationkey
          in: formData
          required: true
          type: string
          format: JSON
        - name: member_object
          in: form
          required: true
          type: string
          format: JSON
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Request was successful
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              data:
                type: object
      deprecated: false
```

but it gives me below error

> ✖ Swagger Error Not a valid parameter definition Jump to line 6996
>   Details  Object code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"  params: Array [0] message: 
>   "Not a valid parameter definition"  path: Array [5] schemaId: 
>   "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#"  inner: Array [2] level: 900 type:
>   "Swagger Error" description:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
>   lineNumber: 6996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second parameter has an invalid "in" value, it should be **formData**.

According to Swagger specification:

**in**: The location of the parameter. Possible values are "query", "header", "path", "formData" or "body".